# pyyaml load number as decimal

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

`yaml.load` loads numbers as Python floats. I cannot find a straightforward way to override this.

Compare `json.load`, which allows `parse_float=Decimal` if you want to parse floating point numbers as `decimal.Decimal`s.

Is there any way to accomplish this with PyYAML? Or is this inadvisable by some property of the YAML spec?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
def decimal_constructor(loader, node):
    value = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    return Decimal(value)

yaml.add_constructor(u'!decimal', decimal_constructor)
```

This allows you to load decimals, but *only* if they are prefixed with the `!decimal` tag in the YAML document. However, you can use a custom `Resolver` to resolve all numbers to `!decimal`:

```
class MyResolver(BaseResolver):
    pass

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
        '!decimal',
        re.compile(r'''^(?:[-+]?(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)\.[0-9_]*(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?
                    |\.[0-9_]+(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?
                    |[-+]?[0-9][0-9_]*(?::[0-5]?[0-9])+\.[0-9_]*
                    |[-+]?\.(?:inf|Inf|INF)
                    |\.(?:nan|NaN|NAN))$''', re.X),
        list('-+0123456789.'))
```

You should copy the other implicit resolvers over from the [default resolver](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib3/yaml/resolver.py#L167). Then, you need to define a `Loader` that uses your resolver.

```
class MyLoader(Reader, Scanner, Parser, Composer, SafeConstructor, MyResolver):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        Reader.__init__(self, stream)
        Scanner.__init__(self)
        Parser.__init__(self)
        Composer.__init__(self)
        SafeConstructor.__init__(self)
        MyResolver.__init__(self)
```

Above, we added your constructor to the default loader. Change that line to:

```
yaml.add_constructor(u'!decimal', decimal_constructor, MyLoader)
```

Finally, load the YAML using

```
yaml.load(stream, MyLoader)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Working proof of concept: https://gist.github.com/jpassaro/4d5812290cdca51a8d3fe03c499d4149